# How can I do a multi-line match on the data returned from Perl's diamond operator

Tags: regex, perl

Is there some trick to do multi-line regular expression matches with `<>`, and loop over them? This example results in no matches when run on files with `\n` as the newline separator:

```
while (<> =~ m/\n./) {
  print($.);
}
```

I need to know the line of the start of the match inside the `while` loop, as in the example.

The goal is to find all lines which have less than 75 characters which are followed by a line starting with a space (the standard vCard way of splitting long lines):

```
while (<> =~ m/(^|\n).{0,74}\n /)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you remember to put the handle in multi-line mode by setting `$/` to the empty string or the undefined value?

The following program does what you want:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

$/ = "";

*ARGV = *DATA;

while (<>) {
  while (/^(.{0,75}\n(^[ \t].{1,75}\n)*)/mg) {
    my $vcard = $1;

    $vcard =~ s/\r?\n[ \t]//g;

    print $vcard;
  }
}

__DATA__
DESCRIPTION:This is a long description that exists on a long line.
DESCRIPTION:This is a long description
  that exists on a long line.
DESCRIPTION:This is a long descrip
 tion that exists o
 n a long line.
```

Output:

```
$ ./try
DESCRIPTION:This is a long description that exists on a long line.
DESCRIPTION:This is a long description that exists on a long line.
DESCRIPTION:This is a long description that exists on a long line.
```

Answer (score 6):

What are you tring to do in that regex? It looks like you are trying to find any case where a newline is followed by at least one character, and then that leads you to print the line number (`$.`) of whatever matches that criterion.

If you don't mind my asking, what's the larger purpose here?

In any case, see this article for a clear discussion of multiline matching: [Regexp Power](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/06/06/regexps.html)

**Edited after the move to SO**: If what you really want is to find the lines with less than 75 characters *and* a next line beginning with a space, I wouldn't use one regex. The description points to an easier and clearer (I think) solution: (1) filter out all lines with less than 75 characters (the `length` function is good for that). For the lines that remain, (2) check if the next line starts with a space. That gives you clear logic and an easy regex to write.

In response to the question about getting the "next" line. Think of it the other way around: you want to check every *next* line, but only if the *previous* line was less than 75 characters. So how about this:

```
my $prev = <>; # Initialize $prev with the first line

while (<>) {
    # Add 1 to 75 for newline or chomp it perhaps?
    if (length $prev < 76) {
        print "$.: $_" if $_ =~ m/^\s/;
    }
    $prev = $_;
}
```

(Note that I don't know anything about vCard format and that `\s` is broader than literally "a single space." So you may need to adjust that code to fit your problem better.)

Comment: Thanks for the link; unfortunately there's no mention of file handles there that I can find. Maybe the direction is wrong for this sort of matching, but I was hoping to be able to use `$.` instead of keeping track of a line count and/or keeping track of the previous line.

Comment: Sounds good, but how do I get the next line without removing it from <>?

Comment: @l0b0: I think you're mixing things together. The article explains multi-line matching with a regular expression. That's what you asked about originally. File handles aren't relevant to that problem *per se*. See above for the other part of your comment.

Comment: Note that when reading via `<>` the value of `$.` is *not* reset across files. See `perldoc -f eof` for how to do it manually if that's important to you.

Comment: @Michael: It's a good point (and once upon a time, I meant to say that here, but this question moved around a bunch (literally and figuratively)).

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a file with arbitrary text mixed with vCards?

If all you have is a bunch of vCards in file and you want to parse them, there some [vCard parsing modules on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=vcard&mode=module).

See, for example, [Text::vCard](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-vCard/), specifically [Text::vCard::Addressbook](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::vCard::Addressbook).

Regarding,

```
while (<> =~ m/\n./) {
  print($.);
}
```

This would indeed not match anything because of the simple fact that input is read line-by-line meaning there cannot be anything in `$_` after the newline.

**If** there never be more than single continuation line following each line shorter than 76 characters, the following might fulfill the requirements:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

for 
( 
    my $this = <>, my $next = <>;
    defined ($next = <>);
    close ARGV if eof
) 
{
    printf "%s : %d\n", $ARGV, $. - 1 if 76 > length $this and $next =~ /^ /;
}
```